# Adaptar la altura de un div a otro div CSS

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando que el `div` de color `negro` se adapte a la altura del `div` de color `amarillo`. El `div` de color `amarillo` tiene la propiedad `top: 320px;` en este ejemplo, pero va ser dinamico, su propiedad cambiara constantemente...

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body> 
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="width: 50%; height: 600px; background-color: blue;">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="width: 50%; height: 600px; background-color: black;">
            <div style="position: relative; top: 320px; background-color: yellow; height: 600px;">
                <h2 style="font-size: 100px; color: black;">CUADRO AMARILLO</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y si le pones un height: auto al div negro ?

Comment: @MarioAClaymation Muchas gracias por tu comentario, no funciona....

Comment: Los divs azul y negro ocupan toda la pantalla ?

Answer (score 3):

Sí he entendido bien, quieres que el div color negro y el azul, siempre tengan la altura del div amarillo y que solo tengas que usar css?

**Has probado con flex?**

Al contenedor principal, solo debes aplicarle:

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

Esto obliga a los hijos, en este caso **negro** y **azul** a tomar la misma altura del padre.

Y si le das una altura al **amarillo**, pues esta es la única que determina la altura de **negro** y azul**.

Ahora, si no vas a declarar o asignar ninguna altura al elemento amarillo, va a seguir funcionando siempre y cuando le metas contenido, es decir, si solo va a crecer con un texto que coloques dentro, este mismo tamaño va a tener tanto el elemento negro como el amarillo.

---

Otra cosas que puedes intentar es usar variable css (custom properties), en las cuales puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
.contenedor-principal{
  -altura-yellow: 100px;
}

.negro{
  height: var(--atura-yellow);
}

.yellow{
  height: var(--altura-yellow);
}
```

O sí vas asignar el tamaño de amarillo dinamicamente mediante js, puedes usar la variable, así:

```
<div class="contenedor" style="-altura-yellow: 100px">
  <div class="blue" style="height: var(--altura-yellow)">
  <div class="black" style="height: var(--altura-yellow)">
    div class="yellow" style="height: var(--altura-yellow)">
  </div>
</div>
```

O combinar las dos, algo así:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  --h: 120px;
}

.col{  
  width: 50%;
}

.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}

.black{
  background-color: black;
}

.yellow{
  transform: translateY(50px);
  background-color: yellow;
  height: var(--h);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col blue">
  </div>
  <div class="col black">
    <div class="yellow">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Mira como también crece sin necesidad de asignar altura, solo contenido a amarillo:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.col{  
  width: 50%;
}

.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}

.black{
  background-color: black;
}

.yellow{
  transform: translateY(50px);
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 20vmin;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col blue">
  </div>
  <div class="col black">
    <div class="yellow" contenteditable>
      Aqui va a ir X contenido, sí quieres escribe algo, este elemento es editable para poder hacer un mejor ejemplo
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Por si acaso, pongo tu mismo código acá abajo, para que veas como te lo propongo:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body> 
  <div class="container" style="--y: 600px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="width: 50%; height: var(--y); background-color: blue;">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="width: 50%; height: var(--y); background-color: black;">
            <div style="position: relative; top: 50px; background-color: yellow; height: var(--y);">
                <h2 style="font-size: 100px; color: black;">CUADRO AMARILLO</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Si no es esto, podrías explicar mejor que quieres lograr porque seguimos sin comprender.

Answer (score 2):

Los elementos siempre se adaptan al tamaño de su contenido excepto cuando le das un tamaño fijo en tu caso cuando le dices al `div negro` que sea de tamaño 600px pues de ese tamaño será y no cambiará. Ahora lo que creo que quieres es que sea al menos de ese tamaño y si es necesario que cambie para adaptarse al contenido del `div amarillo`, para esto usamos la propiedad `min-height`. Sin embargo tu estas utilizando la propiedad `top` que en objetos con `position: relative` hacen que se mueva una cierta cantidad de altura (px, em, rem, etc) desde el borde del elemento padre **pero** sin que el elemento padre se entere de esto por lo que este seguirá "pensando" que el elemento esta en cierta posición y se auto ajusta a esta posición, te aconsejo cambiar la propiedad `top` por `margin-top` de otro modo no podrás lograr lo que quieres

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body> 
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="width: 50%; height: 600px; background-color: blue;">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="width: 50%; min-height: 600px; background-color: black;">
            <div style="position: relative; margin-top: 320px; background-color: yellow; height: 600px;">
                <h2 style="font-size: 100px; color: black;">CUADRO AMARILLO</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza una clase css para definir la altura, y aplica la misma clase a ambos divs :

```
.div_height {
    height: 600px;
}
```

Y en los divs:

```
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 div_height" style="width: 50%; background-color: black;">
        <div class="div_height" style="position: relative; top: 320px; background-color: yellow;">
            <h2 style="font-size: 100px; color: black;">CUADRO AMARILLO</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

De esa forma, al modificar la altura en la clase, actualizara ambos.

Basado en tu petición, para un manejo mas avanzado, hay otras 2 formas:

[Forma 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860710/website-2-divs-to-auto-adjust-height)

[Forma 2 con Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665476/how-can-i-make-a-div-auto-adjust-its-height-between-two-divs-according-to-windo)

Espero te sirva

Comment: No es lo que busco, pero gracias por tu comentario. Necesito que el div del cuadro negro se ajuste al cuadro amarillo, algo asi como un heigth: auto; o que se yo... Algun display....

Comment: Que tan bien estas en ingles para enviarte algunos ejemplos que te podrian servir ?

Comment: pos manda a ver si encuentro alguna solución al problema.

Comment: Actualize mi respuesta para que checkes.